# convert 1,200,000 to the word 1,2 Million

Tags: numbers, preg-replace

I am trying to use this:

```
$string= 1,200,000
$pattern  = '/,\d{3},\d{3}$/i';
$replacement = ' Million';
preg_replace($pattern , $replacement, $string);
```

should be return `1.2 Million`

but just returns `1 Million`

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Will there be any other words you want to convert as well (such as billion, thousand)?

Comment: Might fall under the more general question of "How to 'humanize' large numbers"? A regular expression may not even be relevant. Also, make sure to post *valid* code.

Comment: i'm not good with regular expression, with that code put 1,200,000,000 and `$replacement = ' Billion'` it's will return 1,200 Billion. i wanna same result but in Million

Answer (score 0):

i was found the answer for myselt very simple

```
function number_convert($int)
    {
         $value=str_replace(".","",$int);
         $value=str_replace(",","",$value);
         return ($value/1000000)." Million";
    }
```

but just around Million